# config.extraPlugins = 'Audio'; not working in ckedtior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins, ckeditor

I want add plugins audio html 5 and video html 5

but

### code (config.extraPlugins)   not working in ckedtior

code (config.extraPlugins) when writing in file config Disappear toolbar all and not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqm0K.jpg)

but delelet code (config.extraPlugins) showing up toolbar and working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4Qpn.jpg)

```js
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {

     config.extraPlugins = 'Audio';
                config.extraPlugins = 'html5video';

  // Define changes to default configuration here.
  // For complete reference see:
  // http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.configuration
   config.language = 'en';

  // The toolbar groups arrangement, optimized for two toolbar rows.
  config.toolbarGroups = [
   { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
   { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
   { name: 'links' },
   { name: 'insert' },
   { name: 'forms' },
   { name: 'tools' },
   { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
   { name: 'others' },
   '/',
   { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
   { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
   { name: 'styles' },
   { name: 'colors' },
   { name: 'about' }
  ];
  

  // Remove some buttons provided by the standard plugins, which are
  // not needed in the Standard(s) toolbar.
  config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';

  // Set the most common block elements.
  config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
  // Simplify the dialog windows.
  config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
   config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=files';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'ckeditor/kcfinder/upload.php?opener=ckeditor&type=flash';
 };
```

Comment: You mean new buttons aren't showing up on the toolbar?

Comment: code (config.extraPlugins) when writing in config

Disappear toolbar all and not working 

but 
delelet code   (config.extraPlugins) 

showing up toolbar and working

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, maybe update your question with a screenshot of those problems you experience?

Comment: ok will update my question

Comment: you can now check question now

Comment: I think the configuration should be: `config.extraPlugins = 'Audio, html5video';` I would also check the [console messages](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) in your browser when trying to run the page with CKeditor for any errors. Also on the page of CKeditor there's a [builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder) where your can configure the editor pack with the set of plugins that you need (including HTML5 audio & video)

Answer (score 0):

You should use config.extraPlugins only once, otherwise you're overwriting the declaration. If you are going to add more than one extra plugin, the extraPlugins option expects a list of comma separated plugins. In your case it should be:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'Audio,html5video';
```

CKEditor's documentation: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraPlugins